# How to change size this CircularImageView library by clicked on?

Tags: android, fragment, android-imageview

I use this library : https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

I want to use this CircularImageView in a fragment and if I click view, it will shrink with its size by animation. What can I do?

My screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaxGE.jpg

this is my code:

```
CircularImageView circularImageView = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
// Set Border
circularImageView.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GrayLight));
circularImageView.setBorderWidth(10);
// Add Shadow with default param
circularImageView.addShadow();
// or with custom param
circularImageView.setShadowRadius(15);
circularImageView.setShadowColor(Color.RED);

        circularImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                circularImageView.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                circularImageView.setBorderWidth(20);
            }
        });
```

Please help me.

Comment: can you give a screenshot

Comment: Shrinking basically means scaling down. My guess is you're looking for ScaleAnimation.

Comment: Something like the second item in the image below:https://imgur.com/a/7Pxr3

Comment: like the second SeekBar in the gif: https://imgur.com/a/7Pxr3